# Is there a word for the phenomenon where explicitly stating assumed things, unprompted, makes you question their validity?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, contradiction

An example might be if someone were to say they were, "A tooth dentist". As a dentist, I assumed they worked on teeth, but as they explicitly stated 'tooth' you would question why they felt the need to add that - ultimately reducing the trust in the sentence.

Another example might a group of adults reading some text (eg. a book) and someone says, unprompted, "I can read". It was assumed everyone in the group could read, yet someone explicitly saying that without being directly questioned would cast doubt.

The "tooth dentist" is an example of a semantic pleonasm or redundancy, but that alone doesn't imply that the validity of the statement is brought into question. The "I can read" example is stating the obvious to such an extent that its only consequence is to provoke uncertainty.

Answer (score 2):

As you point out, the examples are of two different phenomena (awkward *redundancy* and *stating the obvious*),  either of which might prompt you to question the truth of a statement or its implications depending on the social situation.

Rather than looking for a linguistic term that encompasses both (and possibly other) phenomena, such as hesitations and unusual word choice, I would look at the *pragmatic value* such utterances have in a conversation. They could be classified as one or more of terms below, the choice depending on how certain you are in your judgement, which might take additional factors into account, such as intonation and body language.

All of these nouns refer to signs, spoken or otherwise, that may affect the reliability of information, possibly  revealing contradictions, untruths, information below the surface, and the like.

**tell** (n.)

> A revealing gesture, expression, etc., that is likened to a poker
> player's tell
>
> *But his eyes darted fractionally to one side as he said it …; the classic liar's tell.* — Stephen King
>
> Broadly : SIGN, INDICATION
>
> *I talked to staffers who said that their bosses had two or three flights booked getting out of town, a big tell that there was not
> going to be a deal.* — Kelly O'Donnell [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tell)

**tip-off** (n.)

> WARNING, TIP
>
> A telltale sign [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tip-off)

**giveaway** (n.)

> An unintentional revelation or betrayal [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/giveaway)

**dead giveaway** (n.)

> Something that shows (the truth about something) clearly
>
> *The camera is a dead giveaway that you're a tourist.* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dead%20giveaway)

Answer (score 0):

Although I find no nouns, three adjectives come to mind:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supernumerary)
>
> Supernumerary:
>
> exceeding what is necessary, required

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superfluous)
>
> Superfluous:
>
> exceeding what is sufficient or necessary

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supererogatory)
>
> Supererogatory:
>
> observed or performed to an extent not enjoined or required

Of the three I prefer the last because it has the overtone that the remarks are not only unnecessary, but were not even requested (enjoined). And - as you suggest - not being requested, they arouse distrust or suspicion of the reasons for saying them.

> [Vocabulary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/supererogatory)
>
> Something that is supererogatory goes way beyond what’s required. Washing all the dishes, sweeping the floor, and taking out the trash would be supererogatory if your dad only asked you to put your plate in the dishwasher.

If using it,  beware the spelling: the “e” in the middle is a little unexpected unless one has etymological experience.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think one could club together the two scenarios provided in the question. Merely prefixing "tooth" before "dentist" could potentially tell us nothing about why the speaker chose the superfluity: it could be a solecism, it could be a deliberate attempt at humor, irony, or sarcasm.

One could argue likewise for the other scenario. However, if the utterance "I can read" stems from some unconscious urge with nothing seemingly prompting it, one might argue it's an example of **reaction formation.** [*The lady doth protest too much.*]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_formation